How can I prevent my cookies being blocked as Third Party Cookies?
I have an authentication workflow as follows:

From the client myclient.com I send encrypted user and password credentials in x-authorization header in a request to API entpoint example.net/login
the response of this request sends back authorization cookies set with set-cookie in the header.
The cookies are used in a subsequent request to example.net/user, where the endpoint validates the cookies.

Now, with current and upcoming policies regarding Third Party Cookies, the cookies set and forwarded via first response get blocked by modern browsers (it seems) and the endpoint example.net/user returns a 401 status code. It works when the user enables third party cookies in their browser.
Is there still any way of cookie based authorization possible, or any alternative authorization flow at all, without forcing the user to enable cookies in their browsers?
I tried setting the cookies manually in the client via javascript, since the first request also has the cookies as json in its response data. But nothing works so far.

same site cookies are not 3rd party cookies - you're doing something else wrong

A possible solution would be for the server to use partitioned cookies. Do you control the server?

@JaromandaX client and server are not the same site, and the cookies only get blocked with third party cookie policy enabled, hence I am sure the cookies are third party and treated as such.

Oh, well you've made that clear now, your original question didn't mention any domain other than example.net - thanks for clarifying

@HeikoTheißen I do control the server to a certain extend (we have a proxy server inbetween client and backend, the proxy server adds the cookies to the response header). Partitioned cookies are not supported by all browsers, unfortunately.

Please put information about the proxy in your question. In particular, does the proxy run on myclient.com or on example.net?

The proxy is example.net.

I think modern browsers are going to block third party cookies because cookie can contain personal information, so we can't force to avoid this.
So I think you can use localStorage or sessionStorage.
Please consider to use jwt for authentication and authorization.
And you can get and set the token to local or session storage.
jwt is popular authentication strategy.
But if you prefer to use cookie, I have no idea about how to avoid modern browser's behavior. :)

that would only work if the third party site doesn't exclusively use cookies for such authentication of course
